# Does tvOS support notification facility for chat applications?

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, tvos, tvos9.1, tvos10

I am building a tvOS app for the new Apple TV that needs to get notifications from a server every time that a chat message is sent. This notification is also to be displayed on the Apple TV. As much as I understand push notifications are not allowed with tvOS.

With this being said, are there any alternatives to what I need?

To clarify: This is a chat app that needs to display a notification to the user on the TV screen every time a message is received by the user. The app stays running indefinitely, while showing instant notifications. - I cannot use push notifications.

Please let me know if this makes sense, and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We recently built an app for apple TV that shows instant messages from different clients connected to our server. A good library that will answer your requirements is [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) 
Just google socket.io and learn how it works. Basically, you wait for a connection on your server and then you can send messages to your clients. On the client side (tvOS in your case) you specify what methods to run as response to the different event coming from the server.
Good luck.